# Why normals rotate with camera?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I wrote shaders for diffuse lightning.
Normals calculating in vertex shader: **normal = gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal;**
But, when I rotate the camera, the normals are also starting to rotate with the camera. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be generating your normal matrix incorrectly.

```
NormalMatrix = transpose(inverse(ModelMatrix * ViewMatrix))
```

Also, unless you're forced to use gl_NormalMatrix and gl_Normal, you should use shader uniforms and in variables and calculate the matrices yourself rather than using the older model.

If you don't know how to do this, you should find a tutorial on OpenGL 4 to learn the programmable shader pipeline. OGLDev is pretty good.

Comment: How can I get ModelMatrix and ViewMatrix in vertex shader?

Comment: @NoName ".. you should use shader uniforms". Also, I recommend [Learn OpenGL](http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Shaders) over OGLDev. I've evaluated 10-20 different OGL tutorials, and this one by far has the most accurate information regarding modern OGL.

Comment: @Dan Thanks, I have seen changes in your answer. Thank you, OGLDev is a good resource.

Comment: @NoName I didn't recommend OGLDev. In fact, I specifically recommended against it because the tutorials contain some rather frustrating errors.